# running facebook application on android emulator

Tags: java, android, facebook, emulation

To create facebook android native app we need to provide our Android application signature in facebook app settings. whenever i export  some test application and provide the key and class name on application it is working perfectly , i am wondering how to make that workable on emulator... how to create a `keyhash` in emulator ... any ideas?

FYI i am following  the tutorial below
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app which is installed on emulator from eclipse is *typically* signed by default android debug key store, You will generate key hash from using that android key store, add that hash also to the your facebook app setting for android app, So there will be two hashes, one for debug keystore and the second one is generated by the key store which you will use to sign your app to test on real device.